# Excluding "customers"/account holders from our adwords ads?

Tags: google-ads

We run a marketplace website where folks can log in, and we're spending a chunk of change on Adwords lately for our own brand/domain name... trying to diagnose it, we think that maybe we have some of our customers Googling our domain name, and clicking on our ad at the top of the search results to log in, causing us to lose money.

This obviously isn't ideal. How can we deal with this? Is there some way we can "tag" our customers one-time on their browser during login, and then have Google.com not show our ads to them? Or maybe have some logic that says "if they've ever hit our login URL, dont show them ads for us ever again?"

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Nearly everybody searching for your company name is likely to be an existing customer.   Advertising on your own brand name is so cheap (just a couple cents per click) that most advertisers don't worry too much about those costs.   If it is costing you too much money, maybe you just shouldn't buy ads on your own name.   You should be the top organic listing anyway.